# Higher Artin-Schreier homomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, witt-vectors

For the additive group over a characteristic $p$ field one has a short exact sequence of abelian algebraic groups
$$\{1\} \to {\mathbb Z}/p \to {\mathbb G}_a \to {\mathbb G}_a \to \{1\},$$
where the map $ {\mathbb G}_a \to {\mathbb G}_a$ is the Artin-Schreier homomorphism $x\mapsto x^p-x$. Consider now the additive group over the ring
of Witt vectors $W_n(k)$ (for example, over ${\mathbb Z}/p^n$).
Then we have a homomorphism ${\mathbb Z}/p^n \to {\mathbb G}_a$. How does the corresponding short exact sequence looks like? Is there a higher analogue of the AS polynomial identifying the quotient with ${\mathbb G}_a$, or at least giving a homomorphism in one direction?

Comment: What is your morphism $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\to \mathbb{G}_a$ ?

Comment: $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$The analogue of the Artin-Schreier sequence for $\Z/p^n$ is given by the Artin-Schreier-Witt sequence. Let $W_n$ denote the group scheme of $p$-typical Witt vectors of length $n$ (under addition). Then there is an exact sequence of etale sheaves over any $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme
$$0 \to \underline{\Z/p^n} \to W_n \xrightarrow{F-1} W_n \to 0,$$
where $F$ is the Frobenius endomorphism. (One can prove this by, for example, induction on $n$, using that $W_n$ is an extension of $\mathbf{G}_a$ by $W_{n-1}$.)

Comment: skd: yes, that's right but my question was about a different map between algebraic groups over ${\mathbb Z}/p^n$. I must admit I am not sure it has a nice answer: one aspect in which the situation for $n>1$ is more complicated is that the homomorphism in question is not am embedding. Also, the naive quotient seems not to be flat over ${\mathbb Z}/p^n$.